# Fill a Form with controls (according to the data returned from service)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular5, primeng

I am trying to migrate Model-driven-form to Reactive-form.

This is a dynamic form that gets filled according to data from `getCommandPacket`
`this.renderSvc.getCommandPacket` - is getting the data from the server, this is the function signature:

### Server

```
..
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetCommandPacket(int ID){
..
}
..
```

### Html

```
<form>
  <div *ngFor="let key of commandKeys">
    <span class="ui-float-label">
      <textarea [id]="key" [name]="key" pInputTextArea [(ngModel)]="commandPacket[key]" style="width: 40em;"></textarea>
      <label [for]="key">{{ key }}</label>
    </span>
  </div>

  <p-button label="Add Field"></p-button>

  <button p-button type="submit" icon="fa fa-angle-right" iconPos="right">
    <span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">Re-Submit</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

### TS

```
...
export class CommandPacketDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: number;
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private renderSvc: PfServerService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  commandPacket: { [key: string]: string; };
  commandKeys: string[];
  message: string = null;

  ngOnInit() {

    if (this.id !== 0 && typeof this.id !== "undefined")
      this.getCommandPacket(this.id);
    else
      this.message = "No ID Given for Packet"; 
  }

  getCommandPacket(id: number) {
    this.renderSvc.getCommandPacket(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.commandPacket = data;
      this.commandKeys = Object.keys(this.commandPacket);
    });
  }
...
```

how can I achieve the same result but in `Reactive-form` way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `FormArray`. Declare form and within it, declare `formArray`. Then when you get your data from service, create as many `formControl`s as you have results and add them to `FormArray`.

you have an example here:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups

form type:

```
yourForm:FormGroup;
```

form definition:

```
this.yourForm = this.fb.group({
      yourFormArray: this.fb.array([])
    });
```

make a getter for your `formArray`:

```
get yourFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.cpForm.get('commands') as FormArray;
  }
```

and then once you get your data from server:

```
this.yourFormArray.reset();
this.commandKeys.forEach(val =>
        this.yourFormArray.push(this.fb.group({ command: [''] }))
      );
```

that will create as many command (without `s`) formGroups (having only one `input` field) as you have keys in your `commandKeys` result.

PS.
once you set that up you can use `patchValue` on `formArray` to fill it with actual values. something like:

```
this.myFormArray.patchValue(commandKeys.map(key => ({ command: key })));
```

PS2.

to clear form controls from formarray, you can use function like this:

```
//Clear formArray
  clearItemsFormArray() {
    while (this.yourFormArray.length > 0)
      this.yourFormArray.removeAt(0);
  }
```

`yourFormArray` is the one coming from `getter`.

Comment: in the example the you linked to, what do i need to fill in the group `this.heroForm = this.fb.group({` ?

Comment: you need to put `formArray` in there. that is the reactive forms structure that will hold the collection of your inputs (each of which is`formControl`). so, that `formArray` is an UI model corresponding to your `commandKeys`. for each value in `commandKeys` you will create one `formControl` within that `formArray`. Hope that makes sense

Comment: sorry, i was in a hurry and was copy pasting one example from my code and didn't change it all. `yourForm` is a property on your component and its of type `FormGroup`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173794/discussion-between-e-meir-and-dee-zg).

Comment: How can i "clear" the controls from the form? the form.reset() is only clear the data in form, but the controls (textboxs) stays

Comment: i used it like that and its working `clearFormArray() {
    const myFormArray = this.cpForm.get('formArray') as FormArray;
      while (myFormArray.length > 0)
        myFormArray.removeAt(0);
  }` should i create `myFormArray` variable like i did?

Comment: sorry, i've changed the var name. its formarray coming from getter, same one.